# Can we have an if loop for the root section of Quick Union algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

In the Quick Union algorithm imlementation below, inside the root method can we have an if loop (such as if(i != id[i]) instead of the while loop? I think it works just as well. Then why did they use the while loop?

```
public class QuickUnionUF {
    private int []id;

    public QuickUnionUF(int N){
        id = new int[N];
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++) id[i] = i;
    }

    private int root(int i){
        while(i != id[i]) i = id[i];
        return i;
    }

    public boolean connected(int p, int q){
        return root(p) == root(q);
    }

    public void union(int p, int q){
        int i = root(p);
        int j = root(q);
        id[i] = j;
    }
}
```

Comment: because `if` is not a loop.

Comment: Can your explain how it can go wrong, if we use if?

Comment: using `if` in `root()` instead of `while` is equivalent to writing `int root() { return id[i]; }`

Answer (score 1):

A component may be represented by a tree higher than one level. To get the component id you need to go down all the way to the root. For example try

```
s = new QuickUnionUF(3);
s.union(0,1);
s.union(1,2);
System.out.println(s.connected(0,1));  // <== prints false when using 'if'
```